# Use google mobile vision api to freeze the screen as soon as a barcode is detected

Tags: android, barcode, google-vision

The following method is in `BarcodeCaptureActivity.java` of the sample code google shared on GitHub.

```
 @Override
    public void onBarcodeDetected(Barcode barcode) {
      // I want to stop preview as well as freeze the screen 
      // when the first barcode is detected
      // What do I add here?

}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "freeze the screen". Normally, using `Thread.sleep(1000);` freezes the UI for 1 sec.

Comment: What I meant is I want the camera to stop scanning and display the still picture/screenshot of the moment it detected a barcode. On top of that I want to prompt the user whether to scan again.